# Using dynamic "non Domain" Arguments in Typo3 Extbase Controller

Tags: javascript, typo3, datamapper, fluid, extbase

Form-Elements added by JavaScript to a Fluid-Form are not passed as Argument.

- How to do it the right way?
- How to dynamically add Form-Fields with JavaScript?

**Expected behavior:**

1. Form is submmitted to "subscribeSubmitAction"
2. Validation of "subscribeSubmitAction" fails
3. Fallback to "subscribeAction" is called
4. "$subscription" is set and assigned (**NOT HAPPENING**) - instead "$subscription" is allways NULL (but subscription.test is set in the Fluid-Form)

**My Guess:**

- The PropertyMapper is removing "subscription.childs" because they are not in "TrustedProperties" - How can I add them?
- Why "$subscription" is allways NULL - I have no Idea!

**Controller:**

```
namespace VENDOR\EXTENSION\Controller;
class EventController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{
    public function initializeAction()
    {
        if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('subscription'))
        {
            //Try to add "subscription.childs" to the PropertyMapperConfiguration
            $subscriptionConfiguration = $this->arguments->getArgument('subscription')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration();
            $subscriptionConfiguration->allowProperties();
            $subscriptionConfiguration->forProperty('*')->allowAllProperties();
            $subscriptionConfiguration->forProperty('*')->allowCreationForSubProperty('*');
            $subscriptionConfiguration->forProperty('*')->forProperty('*')->allowAllProperties();
            $subscriptionConfiguration->forProperty('*')->forProperty('*')->allowCreationForSubProperty('*');
            $subscriptionConfiguration->forProperty('childs')->allowProperties();
            $subscriptionConfiguration->forProperty('childs')->allowCreationForSubProperty('*');
            $subscriptionConfiguration->forProperty('childs.*')->allowProperties();
            $subscriptionConfiguration->forProperty('childs.*')->allowCreationForSubProperty('*');

            print_r($this->arguments->getArgument('subscription')->getValue()); // => NULL
        }
    }

    /**
     * subscribeAction
     * @param  array $event
     * @param  array $subscription
     * @ignorevalidation $subscription
     */
    public function subscribeAction($event,$subscription = null)
    {
        print_r($subscription); // => NULL

        $this->view->assign('event',$event);
        $this->view->assign('subscription',$subscription);
    }

    /**
     * subscribeSubmitAction
     * @param array $event
     * @param array $subscription
     * @param string $g_recaptcha_reponse
     * @validate $g_recaptcha_reponse NotEmpty
     */
    public function subscribeSubmitAction($event,$subscription = null, $g_recaptcha_reponse = null)
    {
        /**
         * This Method will never be called because the Validation of "$g_recaptcha_reponse" must fail (it's empty)
         */
    }
}
```

**Template:**

```
<f:debug>{subscription}</f:debug>
<f:form action="subscribeSubmit" name="subscription" object="{subscription}">
    <f:form.hidden name='event[]' value='{event.uid}' />

    <f:form.textfield property="test" />

    <!--suppose this was added by javascript-->
    <input type="text" name="tx_extension_plugin[subscription][childs][0][test]" value="{subscription.childs.0.test}">

    <f:form.hidden name='g_recaptcha_reponse' value='' />

    <f:form.submit name="submit" value="Submit" />
</f:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to check the request via Network panel of your browser. Do you see the arguments there? Do they follow the naming schema of `tx_extension_plugin[subscription][...`?
They should be contained in the request within extbase.
Perhaps you shouldn't add them to the existing argument `subscription` but instead create another argument. You can validate it the same way and errors should be available the same way within Fluid.

You can be right with "TrustedProperties" I'm not sure about that. But if so, you definitely should be able to workaround that within your `initializeAction` method.